# regex match if not followed by pattern

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I need to match string like:

> RHS numberXnumberXnumber

contained in strings like these: (all numbers can have the decimal part or not)

```
foo RHS 100x100x10 foo  
foo RHS 100.0x100x10 foo  
foo RHS 100.0x100.0x10.0 foo
foo RHS 100x100.0x100x10 foo  
foo RHS 10.0x100.0x10.0x10.0 foo
```

I've written this:

> RHS \d+.?\d?x\d+.?\d?x\d+.?\d

but this regex match also the first groups of number of the following string:
foo **RHS 100x100x100**x10 foo

how can I can I avoid that?
basically I don't want any match if there are four groups of number

Comment: [Add `(?!x\d)` at the end](https://regex101.com/r/7y7F6i/1).

Comment: You need to add a `negativ lookahead` - which @WiktorStribiżew provided. It will look at string directly _after_ your match and the whole match is discarded if the negative lookahead finds the pattern you defined. Have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions/2759417#2759417

Comment: and this : [reference-what-does-this-regex-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Comment: It looks like a couple of word boundaries can solve this, try [`r'\bRHS \d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:x\d+(?:\.\d+)?){2}\b'`](https://regex101.com/r/7y7F6i/4), but it looks a bit more complex upon a closer look.

Comment: If you just want to use *your* regex and avoid matching the substring in the last sample input you provided, try [`RHS \b(?!\d+(?:x\d+){3})\d+\.?\d?x\d+\.?\d?x\d+\.?\d`](https://regex101.com/r/7y7F6i/5). With the negative lookahead, all RHS with 4 integer parts will get failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples provided are incorrect. Most match line 4, and all match line 5. They're right that you need word boundaries and a negative lookahead, but they are missing a crucial piece.

Regex matches word boundaries before and after dots. Meaning if the third number has a decimal, the search will not run to the end of the line, will not see the final x, but **will** match the string.

As a solution you need to use this negative lookahead that checks after the decimal for an x: `(?!\.?\d?x)`

As well as wrapping the search in word boundaries: `\b...\b`

I tested the string below and it works.

```
\bRHS \d+\.?\d?x\d+\.?\d?x\d+\.?\d?(?!\.?\d?x)\b
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/0nzHkN/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression instead:

```
RHS \d+.?\d?x\d+.?\d?x\d+.?\d?(?!x)
```

Or a compact version of it:

```
RHS (\d+.?\d?){3}(?!x)
```